# Highcharts linked views

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've tried searching for this answer, but with no success.

I would like to have multiple charts with different information on each axis but coming from the same data source. For example, a file with multiple columns A, B, C, D, E would originate one chart A vs B, another one C vs D and another A vs E. Upon selecting a point or area on the first chart, this selection would be reflected on the other charts (so called linked views).

An example of this can be found on d3 examples here: http://benjiec.github.io/scatter-matrix/demo/demo.html

Is such a thing possible with Highcharts? Or would it be better to use D3?

The other point I'd wish to make is that I would need to be working with up to 500,000 points (of course they can and should be down sampled). Is this feasible?

Thank you for your answers as I am trying to figure out the best tool for my needs.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the highcharts, you can use scatter series (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter), but we use clipPath so point needs to be inside plotarea, in other cases marker will be cut.